# How can I get a response from an HTTP server in MFC?

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc

I am a student who studying MFC.
I want to get a response from an HTTP server socket programming in MFC.
But I can not solve this problem.

My code is:

```
SOCKET m_client_socket;
WSADATA wsadata;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
char *http_Request;
char *http_recv_data;
int recv_len;

if (!WSAStartup(DESIRED_WINSOCK_VERSION, &wsadata))
{
    if (wsadata.wVersion < MINIMUM_WINSOCK_VERSION)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
}

// Create socket
m_client_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (m_client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    AfxMessageBox("socket error : ");
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

// Set value
memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("www.example.com");
server_addr.sin_port = htons(80);

// Connect
if (connect(m_client_socket, (LPSOCKADDR)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    AfxMessageBox("connect error : ");
    closesocket(m_client_socket);
    return;
}

// send(m_client_socket, http_Request, strlen(http_Request), 0);
recv_len = recv(m_client_socket, http_recv_data, BUFSIZE, 0);
http_recv_data[recv_len] = '\0';

MessageBox(http_recv_data, "Return Value", NULL);

// Close
closesocket(m_client_socket);
WSACleanup();
```

There are no errors but I received NULL. Help me sir!

Comment: `8.8.8.8` is Google's public DNS server. Why do you expect to find a web server there? You could try `example.com` but don't hammer servers not under your control.

Comment: You need to send an HTTP request before the server would respond with an HTTP response. Why would the server start sending you data after you only connected?

Answer (score 4):

MFC implements Internet sessions as objects of class `CInternetSession`. Using this class, you can create one Internet session or several simultaneous sessions.

Here is an example:

```
#include <AfxInet.h>
CInternetSession session;

CHttpFile *pHttpFile = NULL;
try
{
    pHttpFile = (CHttpFile *)session.OpenURL(_T("http://www.google.com"));
}
catch (CInternetException)
{
    // Handle exception
}
if(pHttpFile != NULL)
{
    CByteArray data;
    data.SetSize(1024);
    int nBytesRead = pFile->Read(data.GetData(), data.GetSize());
}
```

You can also go down to bare bones:

```
CInternetSession session; 
CHttpConnection* pServer = NULL;
CHttpFile* pFile = NULL;
CString szHeaders( _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;Accept: text/xml, text/plain, text/html, text/htm\r\nHost: www.mydomain.com\r\n\r\n"));
CString strObject; 

DWORD dwRet;

CByteArray dataBuf;
dataBuf.SetSize(1024);

try
{

   INTERNET_PORT nPort(80);

   pServer = session.GetHttpConnection(_T("www.mydomain.com"), nPort);
   pFile = pServer->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_GET, strObject);
   pFile->AddRequestHeaders(szHeaders);
   pFile->SendRequest();
   pFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwRet);

   if (dwRet == HTTP_STATUS_OK)
   {
       UINT nRead = pFile->Read(dataBuf.GetData(), dataBuf.GetSize());
   }
   delete pFile;
   delete pServer;
}
catch (CInternetException* pEx)
{
   TCHAR sz[1024];
   pEx->GetErrorMessage(sz, 1024);
   pEx->Delete();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can see "error C2065: 'params' : undeclared identifier", so I corrected it like this:pFile->SendRequest(szHeaders, 0, 0); But I received only "T?".

Comment: I've modified `SendRequest()` call. Leave params list empty. You should check `nRead` variable to see the number of data bytes received. After that just iterate through `dataBuf`.